# How to link documents on mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose

I am new to express development and i am trying to build a blog. I have built two models, one for posts and one for uses. On users schema i have an attribute posts to save the post when a user creates a post. On the controller, before i create a post first i am taking the user's id from the req.params and after that i retrive the user by findbyid function and try to save the post on user's posts attribute, but with no succeful.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    posts: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post"}]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

```
const Post = require("../model/post");
const User = require("../model/user");

module.exports = {
    new: (req, res) => {
        res.render("new_post");
    },
    post_new: (req, res) => {
        const title = req.body.title;
        const article = req.body.article;
        const id = req.params.id;

        const post = new Post({
            title: title,
            article: article, 
        })

        User.findById(id)
        .then(user => {
            user.posts.push(post);
        })

        //post.created_by.push(id);

        post.save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log("Post has created");
            res.redirect("/");
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by no success? What are the problem/error you are facing? Does post not save in database?

Comment: Yes. the post does not save in posts of user attribute

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems.

You `user` schema should not have array of `posts`. Instead, your `post` schema should have a field named `user`/`userId` to store user ID.
Example:

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  ....,
  userId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"}
});
```

Now your `post_new` function should be like this.

```
post_new: async (req, res) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const article = req.body.article;
  const id = req.params.id;

  const post = await Post.create({
      title: title,
      article: article,
      userId: id
  });

  console.log("Post has created");
  res.redirect("/");
}
```

If you want to stick with your way then the `create_new` function should be like this.

```
post_new: async (req, res) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const article = req.body.article;
  const id = req.params.id;

  const post = new Post({
      title: title,
      article: article, 
  });

  const {_id} = await post.save();

  const user = await User.findById(id);
  user.posts.push(_id);
  await user.save();

  console.log("Post has created");
  res.redirect("/");
}
```